# Using return vs While(condition) methods To Break Loops

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, return

I'm doing a little google interview question. Find the pair of numbers in a loop that add up to the number given. I found the numbers 2 and 6 that make up 8 so I say match = true so that the while loop stops, however it still proceeds until it finds the second which is 6 and 2 however, those numbers I have already found just the other way around and I had expected my loop to break as my if statement states if there is any 2 numbers that give the sum, match = true therefore terminating the loop, I guess I am wrong though.

However, if I get rid of the while statement and just return; once a match is found it breaks without looking for the second match (which I want it to).

Why is this happening, the logic of both seems the exact same to me.

***Using the while(condition) Method***

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[]args){
        int[] list = new int[]{1,2,1,1,1,6};
        boolean match = false;
        int sumNeeded = 8;



        while(!match){
            for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i ++){
                for(int j = (list.length -1); j >= 0; j --){
                    if(list[i] != list[j]){
                        if(list[i] + list[j] == sumNeeded){
                            System.out.println("The numbers are = " + list[i] + " & " + list[j]);
                            match = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

***Using `return`***

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[]args){
        int[] list = new int[]{1,2,1,1,1,6};
        int sumNeeded = 8;



        for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i ++){
            for(int j = (list.length -1); j >= 0; j --){
                if(list[i] != list[j]){
                    if(list[i] + list[j] == sumNeeded){
                        System.out.println("The numbers are = " + list[i] + " & " + list[j]);
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your while-loop implementation, if the array doesn't have the desired pair at all it would result in an infinite loop. There is no need for the while statement in your solution.

After you enter into the while loop, you look for all the possible pairs in the array and then check for their sum. If it equals the desired sum, you make the boolean variable match as true.

But, until the nested for loop is completely executed (i.e., all the possible pairs are checked) we do not check for the while condition. The entire nested for loop is executed in one iteration of the while loop. Then, the while loop condition is checked again.

As by the end of the first iteration of the while loop all the possible pairs are accounted for, there is no need for a while loop.

Moreover, there are other logical errors in your implementation. The correct brute-force implementation is as follows:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[]args){
    int[] list = new int[]{1,2,1,1,1,6};
    boolean match = false;
    int sumNeeded = 8;




    for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i ++){
       for(int j = (list.length -1); j > i; j --){
          if(list[i] + list[j] == sumNeeded){
             System.out.println("The numbers are = " + list[i] + " & " + list[j]);
             return;
          }
       }
    }
  }
}
```

The inner-for loop is modified to reduce the double-counting of the unordered pairs. Whenever a match is found and printed, we exit the function.

You may also add a break statement inside the while loop in your initial implementation.

```
if(match == true) {
     break;
}
```

Comment: by saying j is greater than i, what if i is at 3, does that not mean j cannot check for index 2 and 1

Comment: Oh wait its that because i being 1 and j being 3 has already occurred which is the same as i being 3 and j being one

Answer (score 1):

The while condition continues to execute the first and second for-loop until it's finished where as with return it stops execution entirely from the first and second loop.

To fix the while loop you could use a label and then break from that.

```java
firstLoop:
for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i ++) {
```

```java
match = true;
break firstLoop;
```

Comment: but my while statement states this should only be done while match is false, so why is it that when I set it to true at a certain point in my loop, it still executes?

Comment: but isnt setting the label to be true in my version not meant to break it because the loops are only meant to execute while its false

Comment: The `while` loop isn't fired again until both of the internal loops have been exhausted, which is why you're seeing the different behavior; the `return` will abruptly exit the statement, @B.brown.  If you add a `break` statement in your `while` loop after the value is true, you would see the same behavior.  Breaking to a specific loop would be one way to solve this.